# Hex values in CIL

Tags: c#, .net, cil

Here is a C# code:

```
Console.WriteLine(-1);
Console.WriteLine(-4);
Console.WriteLine(5);
Console.WriteLine(12);
Console.WriteLine("string number 1");
Console.WriteLine(555);
Console.WriteLine(-555);
Console.WriteLine(555.55);
Console.WriteLine(-555.55);
```

and here is the part of IL code

```
ldc.i4.m1, -1
ldc.i4.s, -4
ldc.i4.5
ldc.i4.s, 12
ldstr, "string number 1"
ldc.i4, 0x22b
ldc.i4, 0xfffffdd5
ldc.r8, 555.54999999999995
ldc.r8, -555.54999999999995
```

I wonder why `555` is represented as `0x22b` and -`555` as `0xfffffdd5`?

Comment: Some light reading on the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Consider the result of `System.Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", -555);`.

Comment: Run calc.exe and use View + Programmer.  Type in numbers, click on Hex.

Comment: @HansPassant, why? I know that it's possible to convert Hex to Dec. And so what?